# Sum of filtered values equal to zero

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have written this code to verify if sum of filtered values is equal to 0 or not. Even though the sum of filtered values is equal to 0, this code is not working. I checked the filtered sum format - I see that in some places the sum is 0 ; 0.00 ; (0.00). Please help!

```
Set SumRange = ReconWS.Range(Cells(2, AmountFilter), Cells(ReconRows, AmountFilter)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange) = 0 Then 
    ReconWS.Range(Cells(2, MatchedItem),Cells(ReconRows,MatchedItem)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Value = "Matched to zero"
```

Comment: Is it the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange) = 0` that fails, or the `Selection.Value = "Matched to zero"` that fails?  Try stepping though with F8.  Images and sample data would also be useful to [edit] in!

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange) = 0` is failing to identify the SUM @Chronocidal

Comment: Are you sure you're not dealing with floating-point error? I would probably `Application.Round` the sum.

Comment: If you're trying to verify an Excel function used on a worksheet is working, then maybe you should not use the same worksheet function in your VBA code. Take a look at [this site](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1286-excel-sum-filtered-rows.html#a2) for a function that sums the values of visible cells in a given range. If everything is correctly set up -- both on the worksheet with `=SUM(...)` and in your VBA code, you should get the same results.

Comment: As and when the data is filtered, the sum would be 0 in the status bar below and wherever the sum is in the format of 0.00 or (0.00), then this is not identifying as 0 and ignoring it. Please Help! @BigBen

Comment: The status bar is not the same as the *actual result of the sum*. Did you try my suggestion? `(0.00)` would suggest that the result is some small fraction, not zero.

Comment: I'm not trying to verify an excel function @PeterT. I just wanted to verify the sum of filtered values based on criteria one after the other. If the sum of filtered values is equal to 0 then Matched to Zero has to be provided in the alternate cells.

Comment: I tried using 0.00 @BigBen, but it is considering 0# automatically and ignoring. And also I tried by giving in this format "0.00". But still, it is not considering

Comment: Use `Application.Round` as I suggested. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) for more background.

Comment: Okay @BigBen, I'll just try that let you know :)

Comment: try to use SUBTOTAL i.o. SUM,

Comment: `Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange), 2)) = 0` worked for me very well. And I observed one more point is the above formula is working for 0 & (0.00) and it's not working for 0.00. then I have used `Abs(Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange), 2)) = 0` this is working perfectly as of now :) Thank you so much. @BigBen

Comment: Don't use `Round`... use `WorksheetFunction.Round`... see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function) why.

Comment: Sure @BigBen I’ll do that. Thank you so much :)